# Jenkins - sending email after build fails with multiple recipients

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Brand new to Jenkins so forgive any noob errors. I have a Pipeline with this code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Ok') {
            steps {
                echo "Ok"
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
          emailext (
            subject:'Jenkins Build Test for XUSDK', 
            mimeType: 'text/html', 
            to: 'testuser@example.com',
            recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'],[$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']], 
            body: 'Testing Jenkins sending an email message after building a job.'
            )
      }
    }
}
```

This works fine and sends an email to the recipient in the `to` field. However, if I change that value to:

```
to:'testuser'@example.com','testuser2@example.com',
```

The build fails and I receive this error:

```
WorkflowScript: 14: Arguments to "emailext" must be explicitly named. @ line 14, column 11.
             emailext (
```

My Google-fu failed and I was not able to find a solution. Checking SO, other answers have indicated this is the proper way to send email to more than one recipient. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can add multiple email recipients by placing them within the same pair of quotes separated by commas - `to:'testuser@example.com, testuser2@example.com',`. Also, please remove that extra quote after `testuser`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the below:-

```
to:'testuser@example.com,testuser2@example.com'
```